# How can I debug why stopping threads during GC took so long?

Tags: java, cassandra, garbage-collection

I'm running a Cassandra instance with

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b34)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b34, mixed mode)
```

and the following garbage collection options

```
-Xms20000m
-Xmx20000m
-Xmn10000m
-Xss256k
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000
-XX:GCTimeRatio=97
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=2
-XX:+UseTLAB
-XX:+ResizeTLAB
-XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
-XX:+PrintHeapAtGC
-XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime
-XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy
-Xloggc:/dev/shm/cassandra-gc.log
```

During a garbage collection cycle, the JVM logs the following

```
2017-08-15T17:09:08.506+0000: 71712.670: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young)
Desired survivor size 658505728 bytes, new threshold 2 (max 2)
- age   1:   26818496 bytes,   26818496 total
- age   2:   14940744 bytes,   41759240 total
 71712.670: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) start choosing CSet, _pending_cards: 222556, predicted base time: 50.67 ms, remaining time: 949.33 ms, target pause time: 1000.00 ms]
 71712.670: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) add young regions to CSet, eden: 1242 regions, survivors: 8 regions, predicted young region time: 12.00 ms]
 71712.670: [G1Ergonomics (CSet Construction) finish choosing CSet, eden: 1242 regions, survivors: 8 regions, old: 0 regions, predicted pause time: 62.68 ms, target pause time: 1000.00 ms]
 71712.736: [G1Ergonomics (Heap Sizing) attempt heap expansion, reason: recent GC overhead higher than threshold after GC, recent GC overhead: 1.39 %, threshold: 1.02 %, uncommitted: 0 bytes, calculated expansion amount: 0 bytes (20.00 %)]
, 0.0662411 secs]
   [Parallel Time: 57.5 ms, GC Workers: 33]
      [GC Worker Start (ms): Min: 71712670.9, Avg: 71712671.2, Max: 71712671.4, Diff: 0.4]
      [Ext Root Scanning (ms): Min: 6.4, Avg: 7.0, Max: 10.2, Diff: 3.8, Sum: 232.3]
      [Update RS (ms): Min: 34.0, Avg: 37.0, Max: 38.9, Diff: 4.9, Sum: 1221.2]
         [Processed Buffers: Min: 27, Avg: 48.5, Max: 66, Diff: 39, Sum: 1599]
      [Scan RS (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.2, Max: 0.5, Diff: 0.4, Sum: 5.1]
      [Code Root Scanning (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.1]
      [Object Copy (ms): Min: 11.3, Avg: 12.6, Max: 12.9, Diff: 1.7, Sum: 415.0]
      [Termination (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.0, Max: 0.0, Diff: 0.0, Sum: 0.4]
         [Termination Attempts: Min: 1, Avg: 2.1, Max: 4, Diff: 3, Sum: 68]
      [GC Worker Other (ms): Min: 0.0, Avg: 0.1, Max: 0.3, Diff: 0.3, Sum: 4.5]
      [GC Worker Total (ms): Min: 56.7, Avg: 56.9, Max: 57.3, Diff: 0.7, Sum: 1878.5]
      [GC Worker End (ms): Min: 71712728.0, Avg: 71712728.1, Max: 71712728.3, Diff: 0.3]
   [Code Root Fixup: 0.5 ms]
   [Code Root Purge: 0.0 ms]
   [Clear CT: 1.1 ms]
   [Other: 7.1 ms]
      [Choose CSet: 0.0 ms]
      [Ref Proc: 2.7 ms]
      [Ref Enq: 0.0 ms]
      [Redirty Cards: 0.8 ms]
      [Humongous Register: 0.1 ms]
      [Humongous Reclaim: 0.0 ms]
      [Free CSet: 1.5 ms]
   [Eden: 9936.0M(9936.0M)->0.0B(9920.0M) Survivors: 64.0M->80.0M Heap: 18.2G(19.5G)->8718.4M(19.5G)]
Heap after GC invocations=8876 (full 0):
 garbage-first heap   total 20480000K, used 8927594K [0x00000002de000000, 0x00000002de804e20, 0x00000007c0000000)
  region size 8192K, 10 young (81920K), 10 survivors (81920K)
 Metaspace       used 44399K, capacity 44978K, committed 45184K, reserved 1089536K
  class space    used 4591K, capacity 4729K, committed 4760K, reserved 1048576K
}
 [Times: user=0.88 sys=0.24, real=0.07 secs]
2017-08-15T17:09:08.573+0000: 71712.737: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 4.1542217 seconds, Stopping threads took: 4.0814458 seconds
```

I'll draw attention to the last line

> Total time for which application threads were stopped: 4.1542217 seconds, **Stopping threads took: 4.0814458 seconds**

I can't tell from any of the printed GC details why stopping threads took so long.

Other (long-ish) pauses have trivially low thread stop times

```
2017-08-15T17:09:26.646+0000: 71730.810: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1165019 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0005363 seconds
2017-08-15T17:10:36.982+0000: 71801.146: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1444364 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0006902 seconds
2017-08-15T17:10:42.091+0000: 71806.255: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2288663 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0064196 seconds
2017-08-15T17:10:52.601+0000: 71816.765: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.2781895 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0005429 seconds
2017-08-15T17:10:56.992+0000: 71821.156: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1380046 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0006240 seconds
```

The application has at least 1000 threads, but it makes no sense to me that stopping them would take 98% of a GC event's duration.

I first assumed that it was the time it took for a thread to reach a safepoint, so I tried adding

```
-XX:+SafepointTimeout -XX:SafepointTimeoutDelay=500
```

but the events logged didn't coincide with the long GC events (unless the threads are all taking 499ms to reach their safepoint...)

What else can delay thread stopping time?

Note that these pauses are present whether I use CMS or G1 and whether I [write the GC logs to disk (SSD) or to memory](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2016/02/eliminating-large-jvm-gc-pauses-caused-by-background-io-traffic).

Comment: @the8472 Thanks. Those statistics showed a long `sync` time which makes me think my issue is [this](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8057003).

Answer (score 4):

You can add `-XX:+PrintSafepointStatistics` `–XX:PrintSafepointStatisticsCount=1` to enable details diagnostics on safepoints.

`-XX:+PrintJNIGCStalls` is another diagnostic [option](http://blog.ragozin.info/2016/10/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html) that may shed some light on problem.

`JNIGCStalls` are no counted towards `SafepointTimeout`.

Other reason could be overloaded system in general. I would suggest you to check if spikes in "load average" correlates with abnormal GC. Though "load average" metrics has [quirks](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-08-08/linux-load-averages.html) on its own.

If you are on virtualized environment, sporadic system freezes could be a norm. Such freezes could also be recognized as spikes in "load average" OS metric.